# Mapping for Heisenberg equations of motion Jaynes-Cummings Model With Delta Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the Jaynes–Cummings model for a two level atom, the Hamiltonian 
$\hbar = 1$ for the atom is:

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\hat{H}= \dfrac{\omega_q \hat\sigma_z}{2} + \omega\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a} + g (\hat\sigma_{+} \hat{a}+\hat\sigma_{-} \hat{a}^{\dagger}) 
\end{equation}

(where $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$  are the annihilation and creation operators and $\hat\sigma_{-}, \hat\sigma_{-}$ are the raising and lowering operators for the atom)

With potential:

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\hat{V}(t) = \mu \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty}{\delta(t - nT)} (\hat\sigma_{-} + \hat\sigma_{+})
\end{equation}
where T = period between kicks

So, in coherent state i can find Heisenberg equation of motion for $\sigma, a, \sigma_z$, using commutator $\dot{\hat{o}} = \dfrac{1}{i}[\hat{o},\hat{H}]$:

$$\dot{\alpha} = -i\omega\alpha - ig\sigma_{-} \tag{3}$$
$$\dot\sigma_{-} = -i\omega_q\sigma_{-} - ig\alpha\sigma_{z} + ig\mu\delta_{T}(t)\sigma_{z} \tag{4}$$
$$\dot\sigma_{z} = 2ig(\alpha\sigma_{+} - \alpha^{\dagger}\sigma_{-}) + 2ig\mu\delta_{T}(t)(\sigma_{-} - \sigma_{+}) \tag{5}$$

And we now that:

$$\alpha = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}(\omega x + ip)\\
\alpha^{\dagger} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}(\omega x - ip)$$

I want to find mapping for coordinate and impulse for this system. But i don't know how because it's very complicated to express them from $(3)$ - $(5)$